# JSONLoader - TypeError: vertices is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I'm trying to import some 3D objects to my WebGL-THREE.js game. I had made them in Blender and after that I converted them with http://www.greentoken.de/onlineconv/ .

This is my code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('images/test.json', function (geometry) {
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xEE3333 }));
    mesh.scale.set(10, 10, 10);
    mesh.position.x = 10;
    mesh.position.y = 10;
    mesh.position.z = 10;

    scene.add(mesh);

});
```

When I open my game in Mozilla, the object is not on the sceen. Console is reporting

> TypeError: vertices is undefined

test.json has included vertices, I also tried to define vertices in .js file, but nothing works. Any help would be appreciated.